# Margin top different in safari than chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress, margin

A bug has creeped in and I can't figure out where it came from. Any help would be appreciated.

If you look at [removed] in Chrome, you'll see that the logo on the left of the nav menu is nicely positioned in the vertical center of the menu. But if you open it up in Safari, it is displaying differently. It's aligning to the top of the menu.

Adding a negative margin top to compensate in Safari messes it up in Chrome.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Personally I would recode this, it's a bit messy. Instead of having multiple divs to try and achieve your situation, put a single `header` which contains the logo and the navigation, then put a margin top on that to get the spacing

Comment: I'm also for recoding it. Using floats for layouts was always buggy and there's no reason to do it in 2018.

Comment: Your layout is very odd. I imagine your issue has something to do with that `#above-navbar` div. You have 3 `.column` floated divs then a regular non-floated div (`#above-navbar`) with no content and a giant margin jammed in between them. Also the `<center>` tag is deprecated.

Comment: @dave Doesn't Bootstrap 3 use floats for layout? Which is probably the most popular css grid framework

Comment: This is all the encouragement that I need. You're totally right. The framework I used wasn't ideal 8 years ago when I built it and it's definitely antiquated now. Time to recode!

Comment: @zgood, Bootstrap 3 does, and it was released in 2013. Bootstrap 4 uses flex box.

Comment: @dave Bootstrap 4 was released 2 weeks ago lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you some idea on how to quickly clean this up, you could do something like this and build upon it:

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="three columns">
      <a href="http://www.1000islandsplayhouse.com/" alt="Thousand Islands Playhouse"><img id="header-logo" src="/assets/logo-300px.png" style="width:114px;height:100px;"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nine columns">
      Navigation
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Some CSS to do the margin on the top:

```
 header {
   margin-top: 30px;
 }
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks for your help Andy!